# TCL - How to print on the screen th messages that where printed during execution of exec command?

Tags: printing, runtime, exec, tcl

Say I have want to execute a script or and executable file by printing runtime the output of execution.

When I do:

```
set log [exec ./executable_file]
puts $log
```

Then it waits a long time and then prints everything at once. But I want runtime printing. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not perfect (as it require writing to external file):

```
set log [exec executable_file | tee log.txt >@stdout]
```

The output will be displayed immediately, at the same time, saved to 'log.txt'. If you don't care about saving the output:

```
set log [exec executable_file >@stdout]
```

Comment: +1: Note that running a command in a pipeline can change its buffering behavior; the expect script `unbuffer` can help with that.

Answer (score 3):

Use `open "| ..."` and asyncronous linewise reading from the returned descriptor, like this:

```
proc ReadLine fd {
  if {[gets $fd line] < 0} {
    if {[chan eof $fd]} {
      chan close $fd
      set ::forever now
      return
    }
  }
  puts $line
}

set fd [open "| ./executable_file"]
chan configure $fd -blocking no
chan event $fd readable [list ReadLine $fd]

vwait forever
```

See [this wiki page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/fileevent) for more involved examples.

In a real program you will probably already have an event loop running so there would be no need for a `vwait` specific to reading the output of one command.

Also if you need to collect the output, not just `[puts]` each line after it has been read, you will pobably need to create a global (usually namespaced) variable, initialize it to "", pass its name as another argument to the callback procedure (`ReadLine` here) and append the line to that variable's value.

Comment: If you're not collecting the output, directly connecting the subprocess to stdout is better.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can launch another process in background before your executable, like tail -f logfile.txt, and outputting the results of your executable in this logfile.txt ?

Comment: So there is no way to get it runtime?